# Could I use the click train identification detector of pamguard when I only have one channel (one hydrophone)?

Tags: noise, pamguard, echolocation-clicks, detector

I have tried to detect click trains of dolphins in my audio file using the click train identification, but it doesn't detect any click trains.

(The recording contains clicks of the species *Tursiops truncatus* dolphin)

My recording has some background noise because of sediments that hit the hydrophone and maybe this is affecting my detection.
Also, my recording was done using just one hydrophone so the bearing parameter of the click train detector doesn't make any sense here.

I attached pictures where I can clearly distinguish visually the clicks and click trains after using the click detector.

These clicks are really close to each other and they are easy to distinguish but the click train identification is not capable of doing it.

I don't know how to be able to detect these click trains using the click train identification detector.
I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank you in advance.

[image: click trains]

Results after using the click classifier and some pre-filtering:

[image: Results after using the click classifier]

When I use the new click train detector , the program crashes.
Results:

[image: results with the new click train detector]

Click train settings:

[image: Click train settings]

Data model:

[image: Data model]

Comment: Copy and send the black window text to support@PAMGuard.org when something crashes - this will work to solve why it happened in the first place

Comment: There is an extensive PAMguard help file on the click train detector - have you looked at that?

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, PAMGuard's automatic click train identifier uses rate of change of click bearings as one of its parameters, so will require two or more channels of data.  And it doesn't tend to work very well when at low SNR - it breaks click trains into very short sequences.

Instead, can you use a click classifier to separate a high proportion of Tursiops clicks from noise, e.g., using click length and energy band comparison?  If so, you could then display clicks classified as Tursiops, and perhaps include a second window to plot time vs ICI.  This won't automate click train extraction, but it may help you discriminate click trains during manual review of your data in the click detector displays.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to use the classifier to separate some Tursiops clicks from noise by comparing click length and energy band.
I have also added a second window to plot time vs ICI but it doesn't show me anything in this window, what is the point of doing the latter?

Comment: Hi Anna - I find the time v ICI display helpful when identifying trains manually.  I've added a screenshot to illustrate how the ICI trends make contiguous trains stand out, in Viewer mode.  The example is a 1-ch file of harbour porpoise clicks.

Comment: cont... If the display is blank, it's probably a problem with display settings - are you using Viewer or 'normal' mode?  In the example above, in Viewer, i linked the scrollers for the two displays, and set both to the same start time and duration.  Then ticked 'display ICI for unclassified' and log scale.  You should be able to display several minutes of data in the amplitude window but scroll through e.g. 1-min windows of ICI.

Comment: cont...  If your question is about the relatively new Click Train Detector module rather than the Click Detector module..., then i'm probably not the best person to try and answer you, as i'm still struggling to understand its parameterisation myself.  This maybe something tha twill help you though, as it should be able to incorporate your classifier, and colour clicks by train on a 1-ch time v amplitude display, i think.

Comment: After some experimentation - the Click Train Detector module (PAMGuard v2.02.x) did allow me to classify / colour click detections automatically as trains on the 1-ch click detector displays.  I imagine when scrolling through longer survey data, having clusters of delphinid clicks highlighted as click trains (as well as classified by type) will make them easier to identify.  They can be assigned to events directly from the ICI display (and as super-detections from a time-base FX display of ICIs).

Comment: Hi Chris - I attached a picture of my new results. I'm in normal mode but I didn't have the proper display settings, now it works for me, thanks. In my case, the click train detector still does not detect anything... Also,as you can see in the image, the classifier does not show the clicks in the specified color for the symbol...

Comment: Hi Anaa - you might need to rt-click ICI display > more symbol options.  In the last screenshot RHS i have it coloured by click classification, and by click train (click trains).  On the LHS it is coloured by click classification, and event.  I don't find the symbol options intuitive to use at all, but here i ticked the options shown to overrule the default symbol shape / colour, and changed their order.

Comment: Hi Chris - I did the same as you and I solved the part of colouring by click classification but when I tried to color the RHS using the click train (click trains) I didn't get the option to do so, maybe because my click train doesn't seem to detect anything... I am attaching new screenshots of the configuration. Also, when I checked the box of "event clicks only" (You had it checked in the last screenshot), it shows nothing on my left hand screen. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Anaa - have you tried the most recent PG release?  V.2.02.05 has updates to the click train detector module.  If not, I would suggest that you try that and then revisit the module and display settings.

Comment: I've tried the V.2.02.05. now and I've attached screenshots of the settings and the results...when I run the click train detector the program crashes but I wasn't able to find a reason yet.

Comment: Hi @ChrisP - yes, bearing is one of the options that a user can select when tuning the click train detector, but it is not a mandatory option. I have de-selected this option and ran the click-train detector on single-channel data.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that there are two Click Train detectors in PAMGuard. The one you are using seems to be the one built into the click detector, which I think was written in around 2006 and hasn't been touched since.

Jamie Macaulay has written a much more sophisticated Click Train Detector module which you will find in the detectors menu and can add to your model. This should work a lot better with single channel data - though never as well as it does with multi channel data. The latest release 2.02.05 also has updated documentation for Jamies detector in the help file.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the information! Do I need to download again Pamguard in order to get the latest release or is there an option to update from version 2.02.03 to 2.02.05?

Comment: Just download and install the latest release from pamguard.org. Existing configuration files won't be affected.

Comment: I've tried the new click train detector but the program doesn't respond after running the click train detector...I've attached screenshots of the settings and the results